# Javascript library to reliably load Java Applets?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Flash users have the wonderful [SwfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) JavaScript library that abstracts browser differences to reliably embed swfs into their web pages.  Is there a JavaScript library like this for Java Applets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle itself comes with [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) for this. Here's an example copied from the link:

```xml
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.5.0/demos/jfc/Java2D',
                      code:'java2d.Java2DemoApplet.class',
                      archive:'Java2Demo.jar',
                      width:710, height:540} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

Comment: did you heard about pulpcore.js?